# Acessar elementos do array a partir do JSON

Tags: php

Estou recuperando um objeto e transformando este objeto em *array*.

Agora, preciso acessar alguns elementos deste *array* para preencher estes dados no *controller* (CodeIgniter), antes de retorná-lo como JSON.

Para o objeto abaixo:

```
{
  "contratos":[

  ],
  "id":0,
  "id_operador":0,
  "pessoa_fisica":{
    "id":0,
    "rg":"",
    "dt_nascimento":"",
    "profissao":"",
    "salario":"",
    "genero":"1"
  },
  "pessoa_juridica":{
    "id":0,
    "nome_fantasia":"",
    "inscricao_estadual":""
  },
  "nome":"Wagner Carlos de Jesus Júnior",
  "cpf_cnpj":"096.686.256-25",
  "emails":[

  ],
  "enderecos":[

  ],
  "telefones":[

  ],
  "crud":null
}
```

Eu estou utilizando a função `json_decode` e obtendo o seguinte retorno com o `print_r`

```
$objeto = $_POST['objeto'];

$objeto_decode = json_decode($objeto, true);
print_r($objeto_decode);
```

E o retorno é conforme abaixo, porém, não sei como acessar o elemento individualmente e preenchê-lo manualmente. Por exemplo, preencher o elemento `[id_operador]` com o ID (*session*) do usuário logado`

```
Array
(
    [contratos] => Array
        (
        )

    [id] => 0
    [id_operador] => 0
    [pessoa_fisica] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [rg] => 
            [dt_nascimento] => 
            [profissao] => 
            [salario] => 
            [genero] => 1
        )

    [pessoa_juridica] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [nome_fantasia] => 
            [inscricao_estadual] => 
        )

    [nome] => Wagner Carlos de Jesus Júnior
    [cpf_cnpj] => 096.686.256-25
    [emails] => Array
        (
        )

    [enderecos] => Array
        (
        )

    [telefones] => Array
        (
        )

    [crud] => 
)
```

Comment: Basta fazer a chamada $objeto_decode["id_operador"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta apenas fazer referência ao item do array. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$objeto_decode['id_operador'] = session_id();
```

Outro exemplo, para acessar o `id` de pessoa física:

```
$objeto_decode['pessoa_fisica']['id'] = 'Coloque a variável do ID aqui';
```

Caso utilize:

```
// Isto
$objeto_decode = json_decode($objeto);
// Em vez disso
$objeto_decode = json_decode($objeto, true);
```

Você pode acessar os itens como objetos, seria da seguinte forma:

```
// Acesso ao objeto id_operador
$objeto_decode->id_operador = session_id();
// Acesso ao id da pessoa física
$objeto_decode->pessoa_fisica->id = 'Coloque a variável do ID aqui';
```

Particularmente, prefiro utilizar objetos pois são melhores para leitura. Mas, isto vai de cada um, veja qual se adapta melhor e, boa programação.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou e esclareceu muito.
Obrigado pela resposta.

Agora consigo incluir as informações através do controller.

Comment: Bruno, sabe me dizer como eu faria inserts em tabelas diferentes, utilizando o objeto acima, exemplo: `$objeto_decode->id_operador = session_id();` iria para a `tabela devedor` já os itens do array `pessoa_juridica` iria para a tabela `devedor_pf`.

Comment: `$objeto_decode->id_operador = $operador_id;`
`$objeto_decode->pessoa_fisica->id = $ultimo_id;`

`$insert_devedor     = $this->devedor->salvar($objeto_decode);`
`$insert_devedor_pf  = $this->devedor->salvar_devedor_pf($objeto_decode_pf);`

Comment: sabe como eu poderia acessar os itens de um array, que está dentro de outro array. Exemplo: ['contratos']['negociacoes']['parcelas']. Neste caso, cada um seria um objeto e eu preciso acessar os itens do objeto negociacoes.